# How do I pass property values from html

Tags: html, angular, firebase, ionic4

```
<ion-select [(ngModel)]="selection" (ionChange)="optionsFn(itinerary.dateRange)">
    <ion-select-option *ngFor="let itinerary of itineraries">{{itinerary.startDate | date: "MM/dd"}} - {{itinerary.endDate | date: "MM/dd"}}</ion-select-option>
</ion-select>
```

In this code the `dateRange` isn't visible in the html but it's part of itineraries.  How do I pass the `dateRange` property from the HTML to a function?

I'm getting the following console error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'dateRange' of undefined

Comment: Where should `itinerary` come from? It doesn't exist outside the scope of `<ion-select-option`. Normally Angular components have `$event`. I'd recommend checking the docs for the library you're using.

Comment: `optionsFn($event)` and from there you can mess with `$event` in your `optionFn()`

Comment: itinerary is just an iteration of itineraries.  Itineraries is coming from a service call to the backend database.  It's iterating over that list to populate the UI with the list.

Comment: However `itinerary` is only created as part of your `*ngFor` in the scope of `ion-select-option`, and you try to access it in the `ion-select`, hence the undefined error

Comment: Is there any way to get the .dateRange property and pass that into the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `value` property for mapping on `selection`.

```
<ion-select [(ngModel)]="selection" (ionChange)="optionsFn(selection.dateRange)">
    <ion-select-option [value]="itinerary" *ngFor="let itinerary of itineraries">{{itinerary.startDate | date: "MM/dd"}} - {{itinerary.endDate | date: "MM/dd"}}</ion-select-option>
</ion-select>
```

Comment: The problem with that solution is that it doesn't retain the itinerary.startDate & itinerary.endDate, it only gives me the dateRange array.  I still need .endDate and .startDate.

Comment: In that case, bind `itinerary` instead of `itinerary.dateRange`. I will update my post.

Answer (score 2):

Your `ionChange()` shouldn't have `itinerary` since it only exist in the scope of the `ion-select-option`.

You can use `$event` instead and bind your `<ion-select-option>`'s value to the `itinerary` object.

Something like:

```
<ion-select [(ngModel)]="selection" (ionChange)='optionsFn($event)'>
  <ion-select-option *ngFor="let itinerary of itineraries" [value]="itinerary">{{itinerary.startDate | date: "MM/dd"}} - {{itinerary.endDate | date: "MM/dd"}}</ion-select-option>
</ion-select>
```

*(I don't know all about ionic under the hood, but for some reason it doesn't complain when you pass an object in `[value]`, it doesn't seem to use `[ngValue]` at all.)*

From there, if you `console.log` your event in `optionsFn(e)`, you should see your object with the dateRange property.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: I realised that if you use `[value]=itinerary`, you shouldn't even need the `$event` anymore. You can access the object that your `ion-select` is binded to (`selection`) in your component